# Replies in Gmail.com interface missing from Gmail API retrieved Thread

Tags: gmail-api

We have a web application that makes use of the Gmail API to automate certain emails on our users' behalf. When the application sends an email, it stores the threadId returned by the Gmail API. It then uses this threadId to poll the Gmail users.threads.get API, looking for replies. When a reply is detected, it pauses future emails.

The vast majority of the time, this works. However, we sometimes get complaints from users that their emails were not paused even though they received a reply. We recently confirmed with a user that the Gmail interface showed him a reply to an email our application had sent on his behalf. The Gmail interface showed this reply in the same thread as our original, outgoing email. However, when we repeat the users.threads.get call with the threadId we have for the email we sent, the Gmail API includes only the outgoing email in the thread (ie: thread.messages.length == 1).

Is this a known limitation of the Gmail API? Is there a workaround to ensure that we can see emails that the Gmail interface displays as a thread? I understand that there may be situations in which a reply does not get grouped with the original, outgoing email (eg: when the recipient changes the subject prior to replying). The difficulty is that the user sees the original, outgoing email grouped with a reply that we can't detect.

Comment: Sounds very strange that thread.getMessages().size() would give you the wrong number of messages in the thread. Are you sure that the user you talk about just didn't received a "response" as a new message/thread?

Comment: Would be interesting to know if 
1)  the original message now still has the same threadId as the one you stored, and 2) the reply has the same threadId

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. StackOverflow is emailing an old address (not the one listed in my StackOverflow account).

The user states that the reply is appearing in his Gmail interface as part of the same thread as the original message.

When our application requests the thread, the original message is indeed present, but it is the only message in the thread. I'll need to do more research to see if I can determine the thread ID of the reply.